# Performance issues in a double $lookup aggregate

Tags: mongodb

The following mongodb query works for me:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'orders',
          localField: 'orders',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'orders_docs'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$orders_docs"
      },
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'products',
          localField: 'orders_docs._id',
          foreignField: 'orders',
          as: 'products_docs'
        }
      },
      {
        $match:
        {
          'products_docs._id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.product_id)
        }
      }
    ])
```

With it I find the buyers of a specific product (`req.params.product_id`).

My schema is: `Products` *hasMany* `Orders` and `Customers` *hasMany* `Orders`

My problem comes when I increase the number of records: for instance with 100k orders (which seems still quite low), 10k customers and 10k products, the request doesn't even seem to end.

I don't have any specific indexes on my 3 collections, however I am only using `_id`s (which are naturally indexes) for my request, am I not?

My question is therefore: **How can I improve the performance of this request?**

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from all the collections

Answer (score 1):

Lookups don't utilize index's thus causing this aggregation to fully scan all 3 collections,
i would recommend you to "start" the aggregation from the products collection since your looking for a specific product id.

```
db.products.aggregate([
      {
        $match:
        {
          '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.product_id)
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'orders',
          localField: 'orders',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'orders_docs'
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: "$orders_docs"
      },
      {
        $lookup:
        {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'orders_docs._id',
          foreignField: 'orders',
          as: 'users'
        }
      },
    ])
```

this will 'hopefully' make the query much smaller, assuming no product is in all orders.

Also consider adding project phases to remove fields that are redundant, this could be extremely helpful if you have a large field as such.

if run-time continues to be an issue consider re-structuring your data to contain smaller mapping objects to lookup on.